# Why using axios to get public object on AWS S3 is returning empty data?

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, axios

When I use curl it comes without any trouble:

```
time curl -vvv https://antivirus-static.s3.amazonaws.com/pt_BR/terms-of-use-app.txt -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "maxContentLength: -1"
*   Trying 52.216.24.116...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to antivirus-static.s3.amazonaws.com (52.216.24.116) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* ALPN/NPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com,O="Amazon.com, Inc.",L=Seattle,ST=Washington,C=US
*       start date: Nov 09 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*       expire date: Mar 12 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*       common name: *.s3.amazonaws.com
*       issuer: CN=DigiCert Baltimore CA-2 G2,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
> GET /pt_BR/terms-of-use-app.txt HTTP/1.1
> Host: antivirus-static.s3.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.60.0
> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
> maxContentLength: -1
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: sLTO+j2y3cmR/c/HRJrdTjmG17nL1fiDcczoJ/kb8CEs0ddZaSQUa1B+MJOHk1K65C/vExHTTi0=
< x-amz-request-id: 4A97D68F2C42E0E2
< Date: Thu, 21 May 2020 19:01:21 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 20 May 2020 15:48:28 GMT
< ETag: "69d0be51e21257480ac0098fd7843d5f"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 16157
< Server: AmazonS3
< 
Termos e Condi�es de Uso

1. INTRODU�O E DISPOSI�ES GERAIS

1.1. Estes Termos e Condi�es de Uso ("Termos") regem o acesso e uso por toda ...
```

But when I do the same request with axios, an empty data is returned:

```
{"config": {"adapter": [Function xhrAdapter], "baseURL": "https://antivirus-static.s3.amazonaws.com/", "data": undefined, "headers": {"Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"}, "maxContentLength": -1, "method": "get", "timeout": 0, "transformRequest": [[Function transformRequest]], "transformResponse": [[Function transformResponse]], "url": "/pt_BR/terms-of-use-app.txt", "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus], "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN", "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN"}, "data": "", "headers": {"accept-ranges": "bytes", "content-length": "16157", "content-type": "text/plain", "date": "Thu, 21 May 2020 18:29:33 GMT", "etag": "\"69d0be51e21257480ac0098fd7843d5f\"", "last-modified": "Wed, 20 May 2020 15:48:28 GMT", "server": "AmazonS3", "x-amz-id-2": "On0uiUG3e2CpvNu/SmMFjTefCuOABMreBngxsU0hXw9wo7rRXqLOKf1X82QzTm1g9s/wSEMox5I=", "x-amz-request-id": "E7C1A12F77B537BA"}, "request": {"DONE": 4, "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2, "LOADING": 3, "OPENED": 1, "UNSENT": 0, "_aborted": false, "_cachedResponse": undefined, "_hasError": false, "_headers": {"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"}, "_incrementalEvents": false, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {"accept-ranges": "bytes", "content-length": "16157", "content-type": "text/plain", "date": "Thu, 21 May 2020 18:29:33 GMT", "etag": "\"69d0be51e21257480ac0098fd7843d5f\"", "last-modified": "Wed, 20 May 2020 15:48:28 GMT", "server": "AmazonS3", "x-amz-id-2": "On0uiUG3e2CpvNu/SmMFjTefCuOABMreBngxsU0hXw9wo7rRXqLOKf1X82QzTm1g9s/wSEMox5I=", "x-amz-request-id": "E7C1A12F77B537BA"}, "_method": "GET", "_requestId": null, "_response": "", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "https://antivirus-static.s3.amazonaws.com/pt_BR/terms-of-use-app.txt", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": {"Accept-Ranges": "bytes", "Content-Length": "16157", "Content-Type": "text/plain", "Date": "Thu, 21 May 2020 18:29:33 GMT", "ETag": "\"69d0be51e21257480ac0098fd7843d5f\"", "Last-Modified": "Wed, 20 May 2020 15:48:28 GMT", "Server": "AmazonS3", "x-amz-id-2": "On0uiUG3e2CpvNu/SmMFjTefCuOABMreBngxsU0hXw9wo7rRXqLOKf1X82QzTm1g9s/wSEMox5I=", "x-amz-request-id": "E7C1A12F77B537BA"}, "responseURL": "https://antivirus-static.s3.amazonaws.com/pt_BR/terms-of-use-app.txt", "status": 200, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}, "status": 200, "statusText": undefined}
```

On my code, I'm already placing things inside the promise callback:

```
      var element = this;
      axios.create({
        baseURL: "https://antivirus-static.s3.amazonaws.com/",
        headers: {}
      }).get('/pt_BR/terms-of-use-app.txt')
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            element.setState({agree_terms_text: response.data, init: 1});
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
            element.setState({agree_terms_text: "Error loading terms", init: 1});
        })
        .then(function () {
            console.log("requested terms-of-use-app.txt");
        });
```

Inside the render():

```
        {this.state.init == 0 ? <IndicatorMessage label={translate('loading_terms')} /> : <AgreeTerms>{this.state.agree_terms_text}</AgreeTerms>}
```

Should I use axios differently to request public objects from AWS S3? Am I missing something on how to use axios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with AWS specifically. The server was responding a UTF-8 encoded file, but the file was actually encoded in Latin1.

So I converted the file with iconv, and it worked.